# MySQL: Join to find non-matching fields

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables.

Customer & Voicemail

`Customer` has 2 columns that relate to this question, `ID` & `Voicemail`.
`Voicemail` has 2 columns that relate to this question , `ID` & `Customer`.

No prizes for guessing that `Customer.ID` relates to `Voicemail.Customer`, and `Customer.Voicemail` relates to `Voicemail.ID`.

I need to obtain the results where the `Customer.Voicemail` == `Voicemail.ID` while `CustomerID` != `Voicemail.Customer`.

I don't need results returned where `Customer.Voicemail` == `Voicemail.ID` while `CustomerID` == `Voicemail.Customer`, as these are correct as they should be.

I've tried using an INNER JOIN but can I use `&&` with it? my mental image always gets fuzzy when trying to use joins

Schema to help:

```
Customer
+---+---------+
|ID |Voicemail|
+---+---------+

Voicemail
+---+---------+
|ID | Customer|
+---+---------+
```

Comment: Just a comment on your table structure, why do they link back to each other like that? Are you trying to create a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: My table doesn't actually look like that, the table is pretty big and used for telecoms purposes. I wasn't the original designer

Comment: Just curious was all, I assumed there was more to it. Thanks for cutting down to necessary columns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing a little bit from your schema, it looks like you want this query.

```
SELECT v.ID AS Voicemail_ID,
       c.ID AS Customer_ID, 
       c.some_other_field, 
       v.some_other_field
  FROM Voicemail AS v
 INNER JOIN Customer AS c ON v.ID = c.Voicemail
 WHERE c.ID <> v.Customer
```

This will pull in all the relevant Customer rows for each Voicemail row, then discard the rows where Customer already points back to Voicemail.

Pro tip:  it can be confusing to use the same names for tables and columns. If I were you I'd redo the column names like so

```
Customer:   Customer_ID (pk), Voicemail_ID, other columns

Voicemail:  Voicemail_ID (pk), Customer_ID, other columns
```

Then you can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT v.Voicemail_ID,
       c.Customer_ID,
       c.some_other_field,
       v.some_other_field
  FROM Voicemail AS v
 INNER JOIN Customer AS c USING(Voicemail_ID)
 WHERE c.Customer_ID <> v.Customer_ID
```

This is probably easier for the next person working on your project to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do :

```
  INNER JOIN Voicemail ON Customer.Voicemail = Vocemail.id AND Customer.id != Voicemail.Customer
```

Hope It helps !

Comment: would I inner join on customer.voicemail? or just customer??

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it was the first to respond, thankyou for your help

Comment: Apparently you've accepted the other, but that's okay, i'm just a new guy happy to help ! :)